# Regular expression pattern for preg_replace the last slash and all the following characters

Tags: php, regex

I can't figure out how to write the right pattern for my preg_replace pattern.
My situation is this: I've got an URL, let's suppose this:

```
$url = "first/second/third/fourth"
```

Now, I need to remove only the last "/" and all the characters after that. So my result should become like this:

```
first/second/third
```

For this moment I solved this way:

```
$result = substr($url, 0, (strrpos($url, "/")));
```

but I know there should be the right patter to be writted into my preg_replace.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use what you have; it's simple and efficient. Less parentheses could make it look less complicated:

```
$result = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '/'));
```

The regular expression would look like this:

```
$result = preg_replace('#/[^/]*$#', '', $url);
```

Just as long, slightly more confusing.

Comment: Interesting how they are exactly the same number of characters :) But which would be more efficient?

Comment: @Soule: I imagine the first one (the regular expression would have to be compiled, and then probably in to something that's less efficient - on the other hand, though, it *is* PHP), but it shouldn't be important.

Comment: "Premature optimizations are the root of all evil" ;)

Comment: Yeah! It work! I'm just a little confused about the use of "#"...but it worked! Thanks...

Comment: @ilSavo: It's a delimiter! Normally, I'd use a slash, but there's a slash in the expression, so I picked something else. Another common delimiter is the tilde.

Answer (score 0):

Match a slash, followed by zero or more characters that are not slashes, followed by the end of the string:

```
preg_replace("/[^/]*$", "", $url)
```

Or, using a non-greedy match (`*?`), this should also work:

```
preg_replace("/.*?$", "", $url)
```